Sum over minimum of indices is less than sum with indicator function?
Is it true that in general, for two natural numbers $n,m$, and a real sequence $(a_n)_n$ $$\sum^{\min(n,m)}_{i=1}a_i\le \sum^n_{i=1}a_i\mathbb{1}_{i\le m}?$$
Because I happened to find this case, but I don't justify the "less" part, I would indeed place equality there: on the L.H.S., the sum goes up to the lower value between $n$ and $m$, on the R.H.S., if $n>m$, then since the indicator function is $1$ for every indices up to $m$, the sum stops at the $m$-th term. Otherwise, if $n<m$, the sum stops at the $n$-th term, by the upper bound of the sum. Isn't it the definition of sum up to $\min(n,m)$?
Example in reference: see row 12 of this paper.

If $ m \le n, \min(m,n) = m $. Therefore $ \sum_{k=1}^{\min(m,n)} a_k = \sum_{k=1}^m a_k = S_m $, and $ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k 1_{k \le m} = \sum_{k=1}^m a_k = S_m $. So in this case the equality holds. If $n < m, \min(n,m) = n$. Now: $ \sum_{k=1}^{\min(m,n)} a_k = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = S_n $, and $ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k 1_{k \le m} = \sum_{k=1}^m a_k = S_m $. Now, if $n < m$, then $ \sum_{k=1}^{\min(m,n)} a_k = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = S_n$, as well as $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k 1_{k \le m} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = S_n \because n \le m$. So, matter of fact, not only inequality holds - as it has been stated in the question, this is an equality, for any natural $m,n$.
